# Composite component parameter does not evaluate when it is a ui:repeat var attribute

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, composite-component, mojarra

I have a composite component that takes a specific object type as its **value** attribute.   It looks like this:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value" 
                  type="com.myapp.Tally" 
                  required="true" 
</cc:interface>
```

The component merely produces a **h:panelGrid** with data elements from the object.

I have never had trouble with it until I tried using it inside a **ui:repeat** structure like this:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myApp.tallyList}" var="tally">    
  <p>
    <qc:tallySummaryH value="#{tally}" />
  </p>
</ui:repeat>
```

When this page is requested, it throws an exception:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /table.xhtml @86,66 <qc:tallySummaryH> The following attribute(s) are required, but no values have been supplied for them: value. 
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.InterfaceHandler.validateComponent(InterfaceHandler.java:233)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.InterfaceHandler.apply(InterfaceHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyCompositeComponent(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:349)
```

Other references to **#{tally}** inside the **ui:repeat** loop do not have any problem.  They operate as expected.   Is this a Mojarra bug or is there something in the JSF specification I didn't understand?

This is on Mojarra 2.1.0 (FCS 2.1.0-b11) in GlassFish 3.1.1

Comment: Never tried this with Mojarra 2.1.0, but it works fine for me locally on Mojarra 2.1.3 and it works fine as well in production environment using Mojarra 2.1.1 (http://www.m4n.nl, that top 10 list is generated by ui:repeat and the star score with popup is a composite). Are you sure that you didn't typo'ed the `value` attribute?

Comment: That's cut and paste (then a few deletes) from my application.  The attribute is auto-completed in the Netbeans editor.     however that is interesting there is a Mojarra 2.1.3 I thought I had the latest.   Let me see if I can upgrade and try it again.

Comment: @BalusC Well it turns out that I have 2.1.3 on my home system.  My laptop is out of date.   And it seems to be working now.  Unfortunately I haven't preserved the failing code but I'll see if I can get it to fail again on my laptop.

Comment: @BalusC Confirmed.  2.1.0 it fails 2.1.3 it works.  If you want to repost as an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to a bug which was fixed in Mojarra 2.1.1. Consider [upgrading](http://javaserverfaces.java.net). I believe it's (in)directly the result of the visit hint fixes as mentioned in [this overview](http://java.net/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&requestId=10432) of issues fixed in Mojarra 2.1.1.